# Response has aready been committed

Tags: java, jsp, struts, illegalstateexception

I have a cancel button which used to just refresh values. Now I have converted them to refresh or reload the page and move to Read-Only page. So changed cancel button to call a function like this,

```
function chkArea(){

        var url='<c:out value="${model.contextPath}"/>/abcHandler.do?operation=view;
        document.forms[0].action=url;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

Now when I submit cancel, I get the following message in the UI,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been committed    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0) ].server.http.EvermindHttpServletResponse.resetBuffer(EvermindHttpServletResponse.java:1892)    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.unprivileged_forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:249)  at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.access$100(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:51) at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.4.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher$2.oc4jRun(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:193) at oracle.oc4j.security.OC4JSecurity.doPrivileged(OC4JSecurity.java:284)........
```

and the console shows the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: The "url" attribute illegally evaluated to "null" or "" in &lt;import&gt;
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindPageContext.handlePageThrowable(EvermindPageContext.java:899)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindPageContext.handlePageException(EvermindPageContext.java:816)
```

I don't see any error in the JS or JSP. What seems to be wrong? any suggestions?

Comment: For Googlers: if you're using `externalContext.redirect()`, try putting this condition around it: `if (!externalContext.isResponseCommitted()) {  }` (This was why I was getting this Exception.)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the problem is not in the JSP or JS in your example<sup>1</sup>. The problem is in what your servlet does when it gets the ".../abcHandler.do?operation=view;" request.

The problem is that you are trying to do stuff that would require a change to the HTTP response headers ... after the headers have been sent.  That is what the exception / message is saying.  (A response is "committed" once the servlet framework starts writing the response.  That is *typically* triggered when *something* opens the servlet output stream / writer ... in preparation to writing the response body.)

To give you a proper diagnosis, and sensible advice on how to fix the specific problem here, we need to see the Servlet / JSP code that is handling the above request.

The "url illegally evaluated to null" message is a bit hard to place.  It could be happening before the `IllegalStateException` ... or after it.

(One possibility is that your JSP code is trying to do something with some 'url' attribute that is unexpectedly `null`, that is triggering an exception.  Then the container's error handler is trying to set a different response status ... and *that* is failing because the response is already committed.)

In summary, it is not possible to figure out what the *root* problem is without more information; i.e. the code.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, you are missing a closing quote for the `url` initialization ... but I assume that's just a transcription error.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you are writing on the output stream from jsp and then again performing some operation on it. This causes `IllegalStateException`. You should not perform any operation when the response is already committed. By committed, I mean the response is sent back to the client. A common scenario is

```
 OutputStream stream = response.getOutPutStream();
  stream.write("something here");
  stream.flush();
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("someFile.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response); // You can't do this because stream is already written
```

Comment: ya so I tried autoflush="true". Even that gives the same error.

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything like the code above in your jsps

Comment: I do not haveanything like above.My actionclass just forwards to a JSP.

Comment: and `stream.flush()` causes the response to be committed. so I feel your `autoflush = true` will not help. It will add to the problem.