# What is causing this WildFly / Undertow broken pipe error?

Tags: wildfly-8

I keep getting the following error on a seemingly random basis from a WildFly 8.1.0.Final install running under NetBeans:

```
08:51:09,742 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-40) Blocking request failed   HttpServerExchange{ GET /web/faces/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties}:   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:527)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:287)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:150) [xnio-nio-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:531)
at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.flush(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:256)
at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.flush(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:162) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.flush(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:100)
at org.xnio.channels.Channels.flushBlocking(Channels.java:63) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:625)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:451)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:525)
... 9 more
```

The requested pages appear to load without a problem, so other than the exceptions in the log, I haven't noticed any breaks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've face a similar problem and thanks to the idea of [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17288638/1614677), I advanced a little it. I'm going to expose my case.

I was creating a REST API using Java (Java 7) (`javax.ws.rs`) and deploying it on a JBoss server (8.x).

My Api responds to these paths:

- `/myapi/a`
- `/myapi/a?filer=myfilter`

So I code it this way:

```
private static final String FILTER = "filter";

@GET
@Path("/a")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object
foo(@Context UriInfo requestInfo) {
    LOG.info("Http request: GET /myapi/a");
    if (requestParameters.getQueryParameters().containsKey(FILTER)) {
            return foo(requestInfo.getQueryParameters().get(FILTER));
    } 
    // no params
    return ...
}


public Object foo(List<String> filter) {
    LOG.info(" > Requested filter"); 
    return ...;
}
```

But I was getting *sometimes* this exception from the server (not my code) 
`UT005023: Exception handling request to ... sessionState: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: Response is committed, can't handle exception` caused by `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe`

Investigating it I come across something really interesting: it was only able to reproduce it from Safari browser, not Chrome. So what? The point is that Safari has a functionality Chrome doesn't: When Safari auto-completes the request, **it sends the request**. Chrome doesn't send the request until the *enter* button is pressed. And this is important because the bug appears only if:

1. request with Safari's autocomplete to /a?filter=f
2. request (hitting enter) to /a

At this point, I don't know the reason (it's something related to the http header) => as stephen-c, *the problem is that you are trying to do stuff that would require a change to the HTTP response headers ... after the headers have been sent*

[EDITED]

I'm almost sure (99%) that we could not handled that exception. basically it's saying that you have lose one request and, as a warning, the server is telling you that you're not going to handle it.

There is another way to recreate the exception: try to put your finger at `F5` or `CMD-R`. Your are going to create hundred of requests... but you'll lose *some of them* (related to pool thread, workers, etc) and you'll see the exception for those lose requests.

I've decided not to worry about this anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same warnings, but only with Firefox. Daniel.lichtenberger's [post](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=55047&start=10) explains well the issue and how to solve it.

Summarized, Firefox's [RCWN](https://slides.com/valentingosu/race-cache-with-network-2017#/) makes two simultaneous requests and cancels the slowest, resulting in the broken pipe warning. To disable RCWN type `about:config` in Firefox and disable `network.http.rcwn.enable`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending multipart/form-data Request In IE,
you must append hidden type to form, like this

```
        <form>
...
            <!-- for IE -->
            <input type='hidden' name='_4ie' value='for IE'>
        </form>
```